# JAVA: Save user input as a string in a Jframe GUI

Tags: java, string, swing

Noob here. I have been browsing for hours, and I still cannot figure out the proper way to get user input to be saved as a string from a text field in my Jframe. Any help would be appreciated. I want to save the user's text into the variable userWords.

```
package cipher;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class cipherApp extends JFrame {


    private static final int WIDTH = 700;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 700;      

    private String userWords; // stores user input into a string

    public cipherApp(){
        setTitle("Camo Cipher");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    

    }   
    public static void main(String[] args){
        cipherApp newInstance = new cipherApp();

    }
}
```

Comment: A good way would be adding a text field first (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html).

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?  The field, getting the value from the field, saving the the value from the field?  Do you want to persist the value to disk?

Comment: Well, I wanted to keep the window at it's full size and just have a text window in the center - kind of like the google's main page. The idea, then, is to 'encrypt' the text and then output it post-encryption through another message (after choosing encryption type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a JTextField and a JButton to submit the use input:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    String userWord = "";
    JTextField userInput = new JTextField(10);
    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");

    public Test() {
        super("Camo Cipher");
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 15));
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // This center the window on the screen
        submit.addActionListener( (e)-> {
            submitAction();
        });
        centerPanel.add(userInput);
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 15));
        southPanel.add(submit);
        Box theBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        theBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(100));
        theBox.add(centerPanel);
        theBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(200));
        theBox.add(southPanel);
        add(theBox);
    }

    private void submitAction() {
        // You can do some validation here before assign the text to the variable 
        userWord = userInput.getText();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I wanted to keep the window at it's full size and just have a text window in the center - kind of like the google's main page. The idea, then, is to 'encrypt' the text and then output it post-encryption through another message (after choosing encryption type).

Comment: sorry I change your layout ^^. I'll modify it for you

Comment: Thank you, I'm learning..slowly, but I am getting there. I guess I'm not sure of what to use to create that text box, since I don't want it in a new window and I want it to be fairly long

Comment: @user1765804 What you mean by a "new Window" do you want it in a dialog

Comment: I am not sure how to describe it. Just how the google main page looks like where there is a long text box in the center

Comment: I think the result looks like what you want. Happy codin

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of BilaDja's code (I mainly changed the graphics). This will make the window size at around half the screen, in the middle of the screen. If you would like to change the size, change the field *'jf.setSize(x, y);'*.

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5624404136485946868L;

String userWord = "";
JTextField userInput;

public Test() {
JFrame jf = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel jl = new JLabel("Test");
JButton jButton = new JButton("Click");
userInput = new JTextField("", 30);
jButton.addActionListener( (e) -> {
    submitAction();
});
jf.setSize(500, 500);
jf.setVisible(true);
jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
jf.add(panel);
panel.add(jl);
panel.add(userInput);
panel.add(jButton);
}

private void submitAction() {
userWord = userInput.getText();
//do something with the variabe userWord here (print it to the console, etc.)
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
new Test();
}
```